# Deprovision and Reprovision for SyncFX not working?

Tags: c#, microsoft-sync-framework

So, I have a sync fx C# project which connects to two databases. I am currently adding provision to both projects, but before I provision, I deprovision first, as seen in the code.

```
SqlSyncScopeProvisioning sqlAzureProv = new SqlSyncScopeProvisioning(sqlAzureConn, myScope);
SqlSyncScopeDeprovisioning sqlAzureDeprov = new     SqlSyncScopeDeprovisioning(sqlAzureConn);


sqlAzureDeprov.DeprovisionStore();

sqlAzureProv.Apply();
```

the problem is, everytime I call the `Apply()` method, it throws the error

> The column 'local_update_peer_timestamp' was specified multiple times
>   for 'changes'.

I haven't used any column `local_update_peer_timestamp` in my database, I've checked everything.

It only happens when reprovisioning, a fresh provision doesn't return any errors.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: how are you populating myScope? try running SQL Profiler just when you call Apply() and see which SQL statement it's complaining about.

Comment: Hey, on another light, do you know how to manually deprovision a database? Code-wise, it doesn't clean up all the scopes so I need to do this manually, any ideas?

Comment: the deprovisionstore should clean up everything. did you use objectschema or objectprefix? which objects are not cleaned up?

Comment: I get errors in between, especially with applying provisioning. So some tables get _tracking tables, some doesn't. I deprivisionstore everything, but still scope_config tables are there. I haven't used any of the functions you said above. Any ideas why this happens?

Comment: if you have errors deprovisioning, then it might not be able to completely remove all the objects. as i have mentioned,how are you populating your scope, and check using SQL Profiler what's failing

Comment: I've found out why it was having this error. It was because I was fetching all the tables from the database and since I've had errors provisioning, it will create some of the _tracking tables. So in some way, when I provision again, even the _tracking tables get provisioned.

I mean I would fetch all tables from my database and I have this one which is Users.Users_tracking table. It also gets added to the provisioning scope thus creating the local_update_peer_timestamp twice, throwing errors. I have now errors about scope_local_id, but I'm getting somewhere. :)

Comment: aside from the _tracking tables, you should make sure you don't include the scope_xxx tables as well

Comment: Thanks. You really are a great help to me this past few days. Reading your answers in previous blogs about this and all. You've been a great help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just putting the actual issue here.

when populating the scope description, make sure you don't include the tables created by Sync Fx (_tracking tables and scope_xxx tables) in the sync scope description.

this normally happens when you just scan all tables in the database, loop thru them and add them to the sync scope description.

Answer (score 1):

Below the basic structure of provisioning using scope (filter), if you want without scope just take:` // define a new scope named ProductsScope
                        scopeDesc = new DbSyncScopeDescription(values);

```
                    // get the description of the Products table from SyncDB dtabase
                    tableDesc = SqlSyncDescriptionBuilder.GetDescriptionForTable(values, serverConn);

                    // add the table description to the sync scope definition
                    scopeDesc.Tables.Add(tableDesc);

                    // create a server scope provisioning object based on the ProductScope
                    serverProvision = new SqlSyncScopeProvisioning(serverConn, scopeDesc);

                    // skipping the creation of table since table already exists on server
                    serverProvision.SetCreateTableDefault(DbSyncCreationOption.Skip);

                    // start the provisioning process
                    serverProvision.Apply();
                    //Console.WriteLine(values);`
```